# Why `du` output / subdirectory size on disk changes after creating a file in parent directory?

Tags: linux, disk-space, ext4, du

```
╼ pwd
/some/dir
╼ ls
╼ some_script.py --create centos-chroot
╼ ls
centos-chroot
╼ du --block-size=1 -s centos-chroot
6320181248
╼ fallocate -l 36613854208 largefile
╼ ls
centos-chroot largefile
╼ du --block-size=1 -s centos-chroot
6320185344
```

I tried copying the directory before creating a file and run `diff -qr` over them, and even `sha1sum` over `find` results once, nothing changes. I clearly don't have anything else accessing files in the directory, no VMs/containers/whatever, no parallel writing, no files are changed, etc. Just the striped LVM of two HDDs with EXT4 over it, in which I create and fill a directory, create a file, and after that the size of directory seemingly increases from `0x178b65000` to `0x178b66000`. Or from `0x178b67000` to `0x178b6d000` in another case, or from `0x178b67000` to `0x178b6b000` in the case I recorded yesterday.

It doesn't happen every time, it doesn't happen on all the machines I tested it on, and once it happens it becomes really hard to reproduce it on the same machine.

Comment: I'd guess that in order to allocate space for your large file, the filesystem driver sometimes is triggered to reorganise free space and that sometimes this changes the number of empty blocks pre-allocated to a directory (i.e. the metadata table of filenames, inodes, etc)